# Cannot Insert string that is an array form: Lumen 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a string that is looks like this

```
`[{"day": 0, "open":"12:00", "closed":"1:00"}, 
{"day": 1, "open":"12:00", "closed":"1:00"}, 
{"day": 2, "open":"12:00", "closed":"1:00"}, 
{"day": 3, "open":"12:00", "closed":"1:00"}, 
{"day": 4, "open":"12:00", "closed":"1:00"}, 
{"day": 5, "open":"12:00", "closed":"1:00"}, 
{"day": 6, "open":"12:00", "closed":"1:00"}]`
```

And I formulated this string using this code

```
foreach($opening_hours as $opening_hour){
                $opening_hours[$c]['open'] = date("H:i", strtotime(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $opening_hour['open']))));
                $opening_hours[$c]['closed'] = date("H:i", strtotime(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $opening_hour['closed']))));
                $store_hours .= '{"day":"'.$opening_hours[$c]['day'].'","open":"'.$opening_hours[$c]['open'].'","closed":"'.$opening_hours[$c]['closed'].'"}';
                $c++;
            }
            $store_hours .= ']';


$location->$opening_hours = $store_hours;
$location->update();
```

but when I try to updated the model it get this error. It needs to be inserted as a string not as an array.

```
"detail": "Array to string conversion",
```

Is there something wrong with it? The data should be like that and I can't change it's format

Comment: What the hell, have you tried replacing all your funcion with json_encode() ?

Comment: @Borjante yep I did

Comment: And why not use that instead? Result of json_encode is a JSON compliant String

Comment: because it escape all double quotes and that is not what the data should be @Borjante

Comment: Did see it at first, but this line: $location->$opening_hours = $store_hours; should be $location->opening_hours = $store_hours;

Answer (score 0):

`$store_hours` is an array

```
$location->$opening_hours = array_first($store_hours);
$location->update();
```

Comment: I need to insert it as an string not an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

```
// To store it as a string
$location->opening_hours = serialize($store_hours);
$location->update();

// To retrieve it as an array
$opening_hours = unserialize($location->opening_hours);
```